# Create a custom Aggregate Function with jOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

#### Context

I am working with **jOOQ** against a **PostgreSQL** database.
I want to use `jsonb_object_agg(name, value)` onto the resultset of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

#### Problem

The join being an `OUTER` one, sometimes the `name` component of the aggregation function is simply `null`: that can't work. I would then go for:

```sql
COALESCE(
    json_object_agg(table.name, table.value) FILTER (WHERE table.name IS NOT NULL),
    '{}'
)::json
```

As of now, the code I use to call `jsonb_object_agg` is (not exactly, but boils down to) the following:

```java
public static Field<?> jsonbObjectAgg(final Field<?> key, final Select<?> select) {
    return DSL.field("jsonb_object_agg({0}, ({1}))::jsonb", JSON_TYPE, key, select);
}
```

... where `JSON_TYPE` is:

```java
private static final DataType<JsonNode> JSON_TYPE = SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asConvertedDataType(/* a custom Converter */);
```

#### Incomplete solution

I would love to leverage *jOOQ*'s `AggregateFilterStep` interface, and in particular, to be able to use its [`AggregateFilterStep#filterWhere(Condition... conditions)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.10.5/org/jooq/AggregateFilterStep.html#filterWhere-org.jooq.Condition...-).

However, the `org.jooq.impl.Function` class that `implements AggregateFilterStep` (indirectly via `AgregateFunction` and `ArrayAggOrderByStep`) is restricted in visibility to its `package`, so I can't just recycle blindly the implementation of [`DSL#ArrayAggOrderByStep`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.10.5/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#arrayAgg-org.jooq.Field-):

```java
public static <T> ArrayAggOrderByStep<T[]> arrayAgg(Field<T> field) {
    return new org.jooq.impl.Function<T[]>(Term.ARRAY_AGG, field.getDataType().getArrayDataType(), nullSafe(field));
}
```

#### Attempts

The closest I got to something reasonable is... building my own `coalesceAggregation` function that specifically coalesces aggregated fields:

```java
//                                  Can't quite use AggregateFunction there
//                                                   v   v
public static <T> Field<T> coalesceAggregation(final Field<T> agg, final Condition coalesceWhen, @NonNull final T coalesceTo) {
    return DSL.coalesce(DSL.field("{0} FILTER (WHERE {1})", agg.getType(), agg, coalesceWhen), coalesceTo);
}

public static <T> Field<T> coalesceAggregation(final Field<T> agg, @NonNull final T coalesceTo) {
    return coalesceAggregation(agg, agg.isNotNull(), coalesceTo);
}
```

... But I then ran into issues with my `T` type being `JsonNode`, where [`DSL#coalesce`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.10.5/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#coalesce-org.jooq.Field-T-) seems to `CAST` my `coalesceTo` to `varchar`.

Or, you know:

```java
DSL.field("COALESCE(jsonb_object_agg({0}, ({1})) FILTER (WHERE {0} IS NOT NULL), '{}')::jsonb", JSON_TYPE, key, select)
```

But that'd be the very last resort: it'd feel like I'd merely be one step away from letting the user inject any SQL they want into my database

#### In short

Is there a way in *jOOQ* to "properly" implement one's own aggregate function, as an actual `org.jooq.AgregateFunction`?
I'd like to avoid having it generated by `jooq-codegen` as much as possible (not that I don't like it – it's just our pipeline that's horrible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Starting with jOOQ 3.14.0

The [`JSON_OBJECTAGG` aggregate function](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-objectagg-function/) is supported natively in jOOQ now:

```java
DSL.jsonObjectAgg(TABLE.NAME, TABLE.VALUE).filterWhere(TABLE.NAME.isNotNull());
```

[Support for the `FILTER` clause was added in jOOQ 3.14.8](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11479).

#### Starting with jOOQ 3.14.8 and 3.15.0

If jOOQ doesn't implement a specific aggregate function, you can now specify `DSL.aggregate()` to make use of custom aggregate functions.

```java
DSL.aggregate("json_object_agg", SQLDataType.JSON, TABLE.NAME, TABLE.VALUE)
   .filterWhere(TABLE.NAME.isNotNull());
```

This was implemented with https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1729

#### Pre jOOQ 3.14.0

There's a missing feature in the jOOQ `DSL` API, namely to create [plain SQL aggregate functions](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1729). The reason why this is not available yet (as of jOOQ 3.11) is because there are a lot of delicate internals to specifying a vendor agnostic aggregate function that supports all of the vendor-specific options including:

- `FILTER (WHERE ...)` clause (as you mentioned in the question), which has to be emulated using `CASE`
- `OVER (...)` clause to turn an aggregate function into a window function
- `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ...)` clause to support ordered set aggregate functions
- `DISTINCT` clause, where supported
- Other, vendor-specific extensions to aggregate functions

The easy workaround in your specific case is to use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) all the way as you mentioned in your question as well:

```
DSL.field("COALESCE(jsonb_object_agg({0}, ({1})) FILTER (WHERE {0} IS NOT NULL), '{}')::jsonb", JSON_TYPE, key, select)
```

Or you do the thing you've mentioned previously. Regarding that concern:

> ... But I then ran into issues with my T type being JsonNode, where DSL#coalesce seems to CAST my coalesceTo to varchar.

That's probably because you used `agg.getType()` which returns `Class<?>` instead of `agg.getDataType()` which returns `DataType<?>`.

> But that'd be the very last resort: it'd feel like I'd merely be one step away from letting the user inject any SQL they want into my database

I'm not sure why that is an issue here. You will still be able to control your plain SQL API usage yourself, and users won't be able to inject arbitrary things into `key` and `select` because you control those elements as well.

Comment: Thank you Lukas! I did figure it was challenging to deal with this in a vendor-agnostic way. I'm away right now but I'll look for discussions about this on GitHub and try to contribute! The last bit was sort of a joke: I just meant to playfully say that "I don't wanna write SQL myself", but I do know it's perfectly fine in this context. Thanks for your answer, and for jOOQ 